# SSRS Reports failed to load in Web Page

Tags: oracle, ssrs-2008

I am trying to build a SSRS report. The data I am pulling from a Oracle Database.  Currently, I have 32bit Oracle Drivers.  When I trying to add the Data Source and dataset and previewing the table. All are working fine.  However, when i try to view the same in Web page.  I am getting the error. "ORA-00936: missing expression".  I am not sure, what wrong with this report.

```
**Additional info:**

Visual Studio 2017
SQL Server Installed 2008 R2.
Windows 7, 64 bit.
Power BI Installed, 32 Bit
SQL Navigator Installed
Oracle Driver 32 bit
```

can any one please kindly advise me, how to get rid of this issue.

Comment: I think we'll need to see some of your code as that error message is generally related to the query or some bit of code.

Comment: @Steve-o169 The Query is working fine in SQL Navigator and as well as I can see the results in Preview in Visual Studio.

Comment: When you put that error message into google, every result deals with some issue in the query.  Additionally, the fact that the error starts with `ORA` is a clear sign it's related to Oracle in some way, not SSRS. If you'd like some help, it usually helps to provide [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The details provided aren't enough to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Steve-o169 you are correct. I guess, there is problem with the query. When I just simply use select * from mytable, it works fine. But, when i am running the below Query. I am getting the above error. I am not sure what's wrong with the below query.

select * from db.customertransaction
where tagged_TO = 'DEPARTMENT' OR LOCATION = 'FRANCE' 
and TRANSACTION_DUEDATE < sysdate

Comment: So the question now is what logic are you looking for with that?  It seems to me that you need some parenthesis around some part of that to clarify the results.  I'm guessing you want `where (tagged_TO = 'DEPARTMENT' OR LOCATION = 'FRANCE') and TRANSACTION_DUEDATE < sysdate`.  You may also need to check to be sure that all datatypes are matching.  Date comparisons like that are often a cause of errors based on datatypes.